# Is there an alternative to Hooking to detect events outside of Windows Forms?

Tags: vb.net, forms, hook, system, handler

I am trying to figure out how to detect and handle system events, such as keys pressed and mouse clicks, from outside of a windows form. Is there an alternative to this that doesn't require user32.dll hooks?

***Rough Example of what I mean:***

```
    Public Sub MouseClick(e As System.MouseEventArgs) Handles Mouse.LeftClick // Left mouse click event raised
        ' even if the user clicks on a browser link in google chrome. Ideally, the click would not even
        ' register in the chrome browser, preventing the user from being directed to the link destination 
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(1, 1)
        Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
            g.CopyFromScreen(Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position, New Point(0, 0), New Drawing.Size(1, 1))
        End Using
        Dim pixel As Drawing.Color = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0)
        ArgbID.Text = bmp.GetPixel(0, 0).ToString
        Dim p As New Point With {.X = ((Me.Width - Me.Splitter1.Width) / 2) + Me.Splitter1.Width - (ArgbID.Width / 2), .Y = ArgbID.Top}
        ArgbID.Location = p
        DisplayBox.BackColor = pixel
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub
```

I want to be able to detect and handle events outside of the form. If I have to use hooks, then this is the most promising example that is supposed to do what I am wanting to do:
[Code Project [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#]](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found a way around hooking to the mouse to create my own event handlers. Here is the summary of what I did:
***Disclaimer** - This approach still uses System.Windows.Forms so you will still be working from within the forms themselves.*

```
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Select Case True
        Case sender Is Btn_Help
        Case sender Is Btn_Ok
        Case sender Is Btn_GetPoint
            If ColorChooserClicked = False Then
                // Doing stuff here
                Dim ScreenLock As New TestFormNi With {.Opacity = 0.01,
                .WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized, .FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None}
                ScreenLock.ShowDialog()
            Else
                // Other Stuff
            End If
    End Select
End Sub
```

And:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class TestFormNi
    Private time As Integer = 0
    Private Sub LoadFormNi(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PictureBox1.Image = Cache.Img
        Timer1.Start()
        Me.TopMost = True
        Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Private Sub ClickDetection(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click, PictureBox1.Click
        TestingForm.Btn_GetPoint.PerformClick()
        Me.Dispose()
        TestingForm.Focus()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Escape(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown, PictureBox1.KeyDown
        If e.KeyCode = Keys.Escape Then Me.Dispose()
    End Sub
    Private Sub AutoClose(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        If time > 30 Then TestingForm.Btn_GetPoint.PerformClick() : Me.Dispose() : TestingForm.Focus()
        time += 1
    End Sub
End Class
```

This way I was able to click anywhere on the "screen" and the click events would still register in the windows form since, obviously, the click position is still inside Windows.Forms; Which also saved me the trouble of having to create a handle to disable clicks from registering in other applications. (Like getting redirected if the cursor was hovering over a browser link)

*Note - The opacity level must be greater than 0 otherwise the form will not register events.*